# How to use WMI to copy a file from computer A to computer B using unmanaged VC++

Tags: visual-c++, wmi, console-application

I need to have my unmanaged VC++ program able to copy a file from the computer the application is on to one of 100 other computers.

I have administrator access on each computer, so that won't be a problem.

It seems I need to use WMI to do this, but I am having a hard time getting it to work properly by looking at examples in: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394558(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I am curious of the `CopyFile` family of functions should work:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This is a console application that doesn't use MFC and isn't using ATL.

Is there a good example of how to do what I am trying to do that will work on WinXP and Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to start by creating a network connection with [`WNetAddConnection2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413.aspx), then copy the file with something like [`CopyFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851.aspx) or [`CopyFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852.aspx). When you're done, it would be courteous to use [`WNetCancelConnection2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385427.aspx) to remove the network connection.

Comment: I had to jump through some hoops, but I ended up using CopyFile(...).  Eventually I may have to go through your approach but for my upcoming proof-of-concept demo this works.

Answer (score 1):

The only WMI class designed to manipulate files is the [`CIM_DataFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class, they include a set of methods ([Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389332%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [CopyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to copy files **but only works in the target machine**, this means which you cannot copy a file from one machine to another using the WMI (at least which you use a network drive or shared).

Comment: Darn, I was hoping that approach would work.  I am trying to figure out how I can copy these files from one machine to another.